# How to use outline-minor-mode to hide some exam class exercises in auctex

Tags: auctex, outline, visibility

I use the exam document class in auctex to write exams for my students. I want to use the features provided by the outline-minor-mode to hide all the exercises I have finished  and only show the one I am editing.
In the exam class there is \question macro for writing exercises. 
here is an example :

```latex
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question % exercise N°1
     statement of exercise 1
\question % exercise N°2
    statement of exercise 2
\question % exercise N° 3
     statement of exercise 3
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

I want for example to hide the statements of exercise 1 and 3 when I edit the statement of exercise 2!
So I have add  \question to the heading list of auctex with the variable TeX-outline-extra like this:
`M-x (setq TeX-outline-extra '(("\question" 1)))`
But \question is not recognized as a heading as expected!

Comment: Too broad. Please say what you've done. Say what you expected to happen and what happened instead. Provide a step-by-step recipe to show the problem.

Comment: I have use  outline-magic-mode with (setq TeX-outline-extra '(("\question" 1))) but when I try  outline-cycle nothing happens

Comment: Untested: Does it help if use `(add-to-list 'TeX-outline-extra '("[ \t]*\\\\question\\b" 1) t)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't properly escaped the regexp for "\question". It should be:

```
"\\\\question\\b"
```

This is a string, and in order to encode a single backslash in a string, it needs to be escaped with a backslash of its own. And in order to use a literal backslash in a regexp, it must be escaped with another backslash. So to get a regexp to match a single literal `\` from a string, you need to use `\\\\`.

The `\\b` at the end of the string matches the end of a word, which is the regexp `\b`.

This will only work if `\question` appears at the beginning of the line. That's why @arashesbati added the `[ \t]*`, which makes the regexp match `\question` with any number of tabs or spaces before it on a line.

Setting the outline level to 1 seems a bit high, I think you might end up folding everything below the question into the question, including subsequent sections. So probably more useful to use something like:

```
("[ \t]*\\\\question\\b" 4)
```

Finally, it looks like AucTex only reads this at the beginning of a session, and subsequent changes to take effect until you restart. So the best way to make this addition is probably via `M-x customize-variable TeX-outline-extra`. That way, you know the variable will be changed before AucTex is loaded the next time you start Emacs. In my case, this variable is defined as:

```
'(("[   ]*\\\\question\\b" 4) ("[   ]*\\\\\\(bib\\)?item\\b" 7) ("\\\\bibliography\\b" 2))
```

Comment: This answer helps very much. Thank you for the explanations!